# Angular Jasmine Karma issue [SortKey] and many elements on page

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

As I am building some pages and adding the jasmine .spec files that karma run with Angular 5,  I am getting a lot of errors

Example on chrome and in command prompt I see

> Error: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'sortKey' since it isn't a known property of 'th'. ("

I am NOT even testing for this `sortkey` so I'm confused on why it would even care!

Here is HTML template code

```
<th class="col-sm-3"  sortColumn [sortKey]="'userid'"(click)="assignsort('userid')" [data]="assign">User Id
```

Then this is what my spec file looks like

```
import { AssignSearchComponent } from './assign-search.component';
import { BrowserModule, By } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

describe('AssignSearchComponent', () => {
  let component: AssignSearchComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AssignSearchComponent>;
  //let debugEl: DebugElement;
  let inputEl: HTMLInputElement;
  let element: HTMLElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AssignSearchComponent],
      imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule]
    });
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AssignSearchComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should create Assign Search component', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  })

});
```

> As you can see, the [sortKey] I'm using on the html, but the SPEC file I'm not testing it.  What do I need to do to be compliant to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Change `[sortKey]="'userid'"` to `sortKey="'userid'"` or if you want to use binding on th (native web element) use `attr` eg 
`[attr.sortKey]="someVariable"`